# ACE_OS:execlp get result - stdout

Tags: c++, operating-system, ace

After several hours of googling I'm still failing to understand how to obtain result from ACE_OS::execlp command. Here I need to obtain not the status itself but the output result. For instance if I call some bash script and it produces its stdout/stderr.

Can anybody help me how to obtain it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this function seems not implemented: according to the github (https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/blob/master/ACE/ace/OS_NS_unistd.cpp)

and the code :

```
int
ACE_OS::execlp (const char * /* file */, const char * /* arg0 */, ...)
{
  ACE_OS_TRACE ("ACE_OS::execlp");
  ACE_NOTSUP_RETURN (-1);
  // Need to write this code.
  //  ACE_OSCALL_RETURN (::execvp (file, argv), int, -1);
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `<cstdlib>` (if supported by your compiler chain) and a code like :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::system("ls -l >test.txt"); // execute the UNIX command "ls -l >test.txt"
    std::cout << std::ifstream("test.txt").rdbuf();
}
```

as seen at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system